# How detect when a window style is changed?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am looking for a way to detect when another app changes the style of my Win32 ListView control.  I do not want to use a loop because I dont want to produce unreasonably high CPU usage.

Is there any windows API to handle this?

Comment: What is triggering/causing the change? Do you mean a LVS_ style or a WS_ window style?

Comment: Another apps using api's like SetWindowLongPtr

Comment: For changes to the visual appearance you could look for changes during painting

Comment: This should be easy. You know that the window style has been changed because you just changed it! If some other program is screwing with your window style, then remove that other program.

Comment: @David yes its some other program. In the question i have asked about a way to detect the change

Comment: The question doesn't say any of that. You should edit it. But if another program is attacking yours, that's not your problem. Just ignore it. You can't defend against a user that wants to do arbitrary things to your program. It's pointless trying to defend against that.

Comment: Im not trying to protect my program. This is a special case is there any way to detect the change ??

Comment: Just remove the other program. Why can't you do that? You aren't expected to cope with arbitrary programs doing arbitrary things to your program. Ask the developer of the other program to fix their program. It's not your problem. On the other hand, did you write both programs?

Comment: Spy++ is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Subclass the ListView control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) and handle the [`WM_STYLECHANGED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632648.aspx) or [`WM_STYLECHANGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632649.aspx) message.